# Obj-C - Programatically display created imageviews next to each other in view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the below code to loop through an array of image URLS, and create `UIImageView` for each url returned. That being said, all of the images are displayed in my view on top of one another.

How can I make it so that each image appears next to one another programatically? Example roughly 10px to the right of each other?

```
NSMutableArray *photos = [self.filteredDataMeetUps valueForKey:@"photo_path"];

 for (id object in photos) {

   self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(37, 515, 40, 40)];
   [self.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object]];
   [self.scrollView addSubview: self.myImageView];

   self.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.myImageView.frame.size.height /2;
   self.myImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
   self.myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
   self.myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so..there are multiple errors you are doing here. So my first suggestion is to buy a book and start studying.

Problems in your code:

- You are always changing the image in the same UIImageView (self.myImageView). You should create a new UIImageView for every photo;
- You are always setting the same frame. For every UIImageView, you should set the correct frame. In other words if you are going to show them one next to the other you should change the X value of the frame;
- A better approach would be to use constraints instead of frames.
- The best approach would be to use a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell;

Other facts:

- In your code, you are iterating using `id object` instead of using the proper class: `NSString *urlStr`;
- I would suggest you: add generics to your array declaration.

Questions like these tend to not receive an answer because clearly there are multiple very basic problems, and it is clear you need to study the foundation of iOS and ObjC (or Swift) development and more in general programming.

Comment: No idea why I didn't think to use UICollectionView for this...clearly my coffee didn't kick in the way it should have. Thanks!

Comment: please if this is the answer you were looking for, set this question as answered.